Number of subsets satisfying condition
I am having some trouble finding a nice solution for the following problem: Let $ M = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 \} $. Determine the number of subsets $ S $ of $ M $ such that there exist $ a, b, c \in M $ such that $ a < b < c $ and $ a, c \in S $, $ b \notin S $.
I was thinking to write S as the disjoint union $ M = A \cup B $ where $ B $ contains an element $ b $ satisfying the condition in the hypothesis and $ A $ is a subset of $ M $ containing a subset $ S $ satisfying the condition from the hypothesis. In that case, let $ \beta $ be the maximum element in $ B $. Then $ \beta \in \{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\} $ so that $ B $ can satisfy the condition from the hypothesis. Furthermore we must have that $ B $ contains at most 5 elements since $ S $ must contain at least 2 elements. I can then compute the number of such subsets $ B $ of $ M $ by going though all the possible values of $ \beta $ and the cardinality of $ B $, namely I can do the following:
Case 1: $ \beta = 6 $
If $ |B| = 1 $ then $ B = \{ 6 \} $ thus 1 choice for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 2 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, 6 \} | a \in \{1,2,3,4,5\} \} $ thus $ {5\choose 1} = 5 $ choices for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 3 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, b, 6 \} | a, b \in \{1,2,3,4,5\} \} $ thus $ {5\choose 2} = 10 $ choices for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 4 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, b, c, 6 \} | a, b, c \in \{1,2,3,4,5\} \} $ thus $ {5\choose 3} = 10 $ choices for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 5 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, b, c, d, 6 \} | a, b, c, d \in \{1,2,3,4,5\} \} $ thus $ {5\choose 4} = 5 $ choices for $ B $.
Thus in total for this case we will have 31 choices for $ B $.
Case 2: $ \beta = 5 $
If $ |B| = 1 $ then $ B = \{ 5 \} $ thus 1 choice for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 2 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, 5 \} | a \in \{1,2,3,4\} \} $ thus $ {4\choose 1} = 4 $ choices for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 3 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, b, 6 \} | a, b \in \{1,2,3,4\} \} $ thus $ {4\choose 2} = 6 $ choices for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 4 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, b, c, 6 \} | a, b, c \in \{1,2,3,4\} \} $ thus $ {4\choose 3} = 4 $ choices for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 5 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, b, c, d, 5 \} | a, b, c, d \in \{1,2,3,4\} \} $ thus $ {4\choose 4} = 1 $ choices for $ B $. Note though that in this case we would have $ B = \{1,2,3,4,5 \} $ and $ S = \{6, 7 \} $ which doesn't satisfy the condition in the hypothesis.
Therefore in this case we have a total of 15 choices for $ B $.
Case 3: $ \beta = 4 $
If $ |B| = 1 $ then $ B = \{ 4 \} $ thus 1 choice for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 2 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, 4 \} | a \in \{1,2,3 \} \} $ thus $ {3\choose 1} = 3 $ choices for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 3 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, b, 4 \} | a, b \in \{1,2,3\} \} $ thus $ {3\choose 2} = 3 $ choices for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 4 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, b, c, 4 \} | a, b, c \in \{1,2,3\} \} $ thus $ {3\choose 3} = 1 $ choices for $ B $.  Note though that in this case we would have $ B = \{1,2,3,4 \} $ and $ S \subseteq \{5, 6, 7 \} $ which doesn't satisfy the condition in the hypothesis.
Therefore in this case we have a total of 7 choices for $ B $.
Case 4: $ \beta = 3 $
If $ |B| = 1 $ then $ B = \{ 3 \} $ thus 1 choice for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 2 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, 3 \} | a \in \{1,2 \} \} $ thus $ {2\choose 1} = 2 $ choices for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 3 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a, b, 3 \} | a, b \in \{1,2\} \} $ thus $ {2\choose 2} = 1 $ choices for $ B $. Note though that in this case we would have $ B = \{1,2,3 \} $ and $ S \subseteq \{4, 5, 6, 7 \} $ which doesn't satisfy the condition in the hypothesis.
Therefore in this case we have a total of 3 choices for $ B $.
Case 5: $ \beta = 2 $
If $ |B| = 1 $ then $ B = \{ 2 \} $ thus 1 choice for $ B $.
If $ |B| = 2 $ then $ B = \{ \{ a,2  \} | a \in \{1 \} \} $ thus $ {1\choose 1} = 1 $ choices for $ B $.  Note though that in this case we would have $ B = \{1,2 \} $ and $ S \subseteq \{3, 4, 5, 6, 7 \} $ which doesn't satisfy the condition in the hypothesis.
Therefore in this case we have a total of 1 choice for $ B $.
In conclusion we have $ 31+15+7+3+1 = 57 $ choices for $ B $. Since these choices uniquely determine $ A $, we have 57 choices for writing $ M $ as the disjoint union $ M = A \cup B $ where $ A $ is a subset of $ M $ containing a subset $ S $ with the desired property from the hypothesis. The problem with this approach though is that for different choices of A, there can be overlapping subsets $ S $ satisfying the required property and I don't know how to deal with those more systematically.
I feel like this problem has a much simpler solution than what I started doing above. Could anyone help me please? Thank you so much.

If I have understood the condition, we're just looking for subsets which have size at least two but we wish to exclude the contiguous ones, right?  But it's easy to count the contiguous ones...

To elaborate on the comments:
The rules request us to count subsets $S\subset M$ which have at least two elements but we must exclude those that are contiguous (thus $\{1,2\}$ is out, as is $\{3,4,5,6\}$).
It's easy to count the contiguous ones...we just need to specify the size and the start.  If the size is $k$, there are $7-(k-1)=8-k$ possible starting points, hence $8-k$ sets of size $k$ we must exclude. Of course there are $\binom 7k$ subsets of size $k$ if we ignore the restriction.
Thus the answer is $$\sum_{k=2}^7 \left( \binom 7k-(8-k)\right) = 99$$
sets of the desired form.
Note that we can simplify this, and evaluate the sum for general $N$, not just $N=7$, by remarking that $$\sum_{k=2}^N \binom Nk=2^N-1-N$$
and, of course, the sum of the $(8-k)$ terms can be computed by standard methods.  We get $$\sum_{k=2}^N(N+1-k)=\frac {N(N-1)}2$$
Thus, for general $N$, the result is $$\boxed {F(N)=2^N-N-1-\frac {N(N-1)}2}$$
Sanity checks:  For $N=3$ we have $F(3)=1$ and indeed the only good subset of $\{1,2,3\}$ is $\{1,3\}$.  For $N=4$ we have $F(4)=5$ and the good sets are $$\{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,4\}, \{1,3,4\}, \{1,2,4\}$$

Thank you so much for the detailed and nice solution.
